# Target large number of unique tags in Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have a scenario where 10,000 devices are each registered with a unique tag (email address). I want to send a notification to 1,000 devices.

Using tag expressions, there is a limit of sending 20 tags per notification.

This means I need to send the notification 50 times in order to reach 1,000 devices.

Is there another way to target a large number of unique tags with a single notification?

Comment: Could you clarify more about your scenario? Do you want to send a notification to 1,000 random registrations?Or maybe you have your own database that is tracking the users that match a specific criteria, and you happen to have around 1,000 matches?

Comment: @MarStr I have a database of 10,000 users. Each user will have registered with the Hub, adding their email as a tag. I want to create a group on the fly using criteria in the database, and send notifications to specific users who match this criteria. When 1,000 users match the criteria, I need to send a push to 1,000 specific users. To do this, I assume I need to send 50 separate notifications, with each notification having 20 tags, with each tag relating to a specific user. Is there a way to send just one notification that can be pushed to 1,000 specific users?

Comment: @MarStr any other thoughts on this? thanks

Comment: Answered below, thanks for pinging me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario of targeting a large number of specific devices sounds like it would benefit from using the [Notification Hub direct send operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/direct-send).

In essence, instead of using tags which are meant to define broader audiences, you can track the user's device ID(s) and send directly to those. It'll also mean you can skip the Registration/Installation that Notification Hub usually requires when a new device is setup.

It will mean more calls to an NH endpoint, because you'll need to call the direct send endpoint for each device, but it should reduce the complexity of logic associated with batching up calls.

Comment: thanks @MarStr. Any thoughts on [Direct Batch Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/direct-batch-send) ? Seems like it would limit the amount of calls to NH endpoint as it can send to 1,000 devices per request

Comment: Even better! Just out of curiosity @desflan, are you using one of the Notification Hub SDKs, or are your writing your own HTTP client?

Comment: I'm using the Notification Hub SDK but have no problem writing my own HTTP Client if required

Answer (score -1):

> Tag expressions using only OR operators can reference 20 tags; expression with AND operators but no OR operators can reference 10 tags; otherwise, tag expressions are limited to 6 tags.

It seems that you could not target large number of unique tags with a single nofification. Also, tag expression using `only OR` limit 20 tags, but this not means you need to send 50 times to 1000 devices. If the devices contained tags you specify before, it will send notification.

If you want to increase TAG Limit Expression, you can vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/12880704-increase-tag-limit-expression) and give you voice to promote this feature to be achieved quickly.

Comment: `[but this not means you need to send 50 times to 1000 devices. If the devices contained tags you specify before, it will send notification]` What do you mean by this please? How can I avoid sending 50 times to 1000 devices? thank you

Comment: At now, the Tag expressions using only OR can reference 20 tags, and you can give your voice to feedback.

Comment: You say sending 50 times to 1000 devices. Your devices has 1000tags?

Comment: No, each device has one unique tag. To send to 1000 devices, it will take 50 seperate push notifications, with each notification having 20 tags. This is the only way to reach 1000 devices. I am asking if there is a better way. Thanks

Comment: I got you idea and sorry to tell you that there is no better way to do it because of the limit of Tag expression.